# How to insert an element in a list after using del in python

Tags: python, list

```
def my_len(lst):
    mylen = 0
    for i in lst:
        mylen += 1
    return mylen

def insrt(lst, what, where):
    length = my_len(lst)
    tmp = [0] * (length + 1)
    for i in range(0, where):
        tmp[i] = lst[i]
    tmp[where] = what
    for i in range(where, length + 1):
        tmp[i] = lst[i - 1]
    return tmp

def move(lst, from_index, to_index):
    a = lst[from_index]
    del lst[from_index]
    insrt(lst, a, to_index)
    return lst
```

my intention was if the original list input is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], then print(move(lst, 3, 1) will give [1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6], but my code gives [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]. Please explain how to fix it.

Comment: How about> ls=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

item_list = [e for e in ls if e not in (1, 3)]

Answer (score 1):

*NB. See the end of the answer for an alternative interpretation of the move*

If you want the item to **end up** in the defined `to_index`, you can simply use [`list.insert`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and [`list.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
def move(lst, from_index, to_index):
    lst.insert(to_index, lst.pop(from_index))
```

examples:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
move(l, 1, 3)
print(l)
[1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6]

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
move(l, 3, 1)
print(l)
[1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6]

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
move(l, 3, 3)
print(l)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

*NB. your function should probably **either** return a copy, **or** modify the list in place, **not both**. (here I chose to modify in place, see below for a variant).*

copy variant:

```
def move(lst, from_index, to_index):
    lst = lst.copy()
    lst.insert(to_index, lst.pop(from_index))
    return lst

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = move(l, 1, 3)

print(l)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

print(l2)
[1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6]
```

#### alternative interpretation: move to the position as defined **before** the move

In this different interpretation, the item moves to the position as defined if the insertion occured **before** the deletion.

In this case we need to correct the insertion position if it is greater than the initial position.

We can take advantage of the boolean/integer equivalence by subtracting `to_index>from_index` (1 if `True`, 0 otherwise)

```
def move(lst, from_index, to_index):
    lst.insert(to_index-(to_index>from_index), lst.pop(from_index))

l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
move(l, 1, 3)
print(l)
# [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Neither version of your code works properly if `to_index` is greater than `from_index`. Because the `pop` happens before the `insert`, the place you insert the value will be off by one.

Comment: @Blckknght can you provide an example? It seems to works fine with the above examples.

Comment: In your first example call, I'd expect the `2` to be inserted between the `2` and the `3`, not between the `3` and the `4`. That is, it should always be put into the list before the value at the `to_index` in the original list. Or I suppose you could make the logic that it always goes after the value at that index, if you'd prefer. But currently, it's sometimes ahead of that value, sometimes after it, which seems unintuitive to me. But maybe I overstated it when I said your code didn't work. I just don't like the API, which might be a matter of taste!

Comment: OK, I guess it's a matter of interpretation ;) for yours you could use `lst.insert(to_index-(to_index>from_index), lst.pop(from_index))`

Answer (score 0):

This would work,

```
def move(lst, from_index, to_index):
  new_lst = lst[:to_index] + [lst[from_index]] + [item for item in lst[to_index:]]
  new_lst.pop(from_index + 1)
  return new_lst

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
move(lst, 3, 1)
```

Output -

```
[1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Comment: The `from_index + 1` you're using for pop is only correct if `to_index` is smaller than `from_index`. You probably want something conditional so that it works for any pair of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you're seeing right now relates to how your `insrt` function works, as compared to how you're calling it.

The way you've written it, `insert` returns a new list containing the values from the old list plus one new value at a particular index. But when you call it in `move`, you seem to be expecting it to modify the given list in place. It doesn't do that. You need to change at least one of the two functions so that they match up. Either make `insrt` work in-place, or make `move` save the value returned by it rather than throwing it away.

Anyway, here's a very simple tweak to your `move` function that makes it work properly with the `insrt` function as you've shown it:

```
def move(lst, from_index, to_index):
    a = lst[from_index]
    del lst[from_index]
    new_lst = insrt(lst, a, to_index)       # save the new list after the insert
    return new_lst                          # and then return it
```

I'd note that using `del` on the earlier line already modifies the `lst` passed in, so this design may not make a whole lot of sense. You might want to modify `insrt` to work in place instead, to be consistent. That would look something like this (which would work with your original `move`):

```
def insrt(lst, what, where):
    length = my_len(lst)
    lst.append(None)                      # add a dummy value at the end of the list
    for i in range(length-1, where, -1):  # iterate backwards from the end
        lst[i] = lst[i - 1]               # shift each value back
    lst[where] = what                     # plug in the new value
    # no return any more, this version works in place
```